# Application.Index results in Compile Error: Type mismatch: Array or user-defined type expected

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

I know this error pops up a lot on the forum, but none of the posts I have seen have the same issue. I get a compile error when trying to use the Application.Index function to slice a 2D array. I have used the function before for simple indexing but there are multiple examples on the web of slicing being done.

Below is the code. It always highlights ".index" and gives me the compile error. I have tried casting the array as double, integer, and variant but nothing works. Please help.

```
    Dim test_z(2, 2) As Double

     Dim new_z As Double

    'fill the text_z array with values

    test_z(0,0) = 1

    'etc....

    new_z = Application.index(test_z, 1, 0)
```

Comment: The code compiles and works on my computer.

Comment: How is `new_z` declared?

Comment: Dim new_z As Double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Index` returns an array if you pass 0 as the last argument. You can't assign that to `Double` - maybe try

```
Dim new_z As Variant
```

Comment: I had tried doing: Dim new_z() As Double but that didn't work either so I had given up. This fixed it though. Thank you.

Comment: I just want to add that index in this case returns an array but it can also return a double if you specify row and column index